# android application that uses the same MySQL database as a PHP website

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to develop an android application that will use the same MySQL database as an existing PHP website.

I have the php codes for every operation done by the web site, for example the php code of making an advanced search.

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this operations on my app.
I assume that I should use webservices, but I don't know which type.

I appreciate yourhelp guys...
PEACE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Easy , You should use Ksoap2 library to implement webservices for android. Check this example [creat a login page in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693850/creat-a-login-page-in-android/6694037#6694037)