# Android code for calling web service giving "application stopped unexpectedly" error

Tags: android, web-services, visual-studio-2008, ksoap

I have trying this for some time now but I am not able to get proper output.I am facing a problem calling the web service from my Android code. My [web service code](http://pastebin.com/KfvTiwAS) returns a string with a delimiter '#' in between. Now i need to make a code in Android that will call the web service , separate the delimiters such that the actual names are displayed using a check box for the user to select

Here is my Android code :

```
    package com.sencide;

    import java.net.SocketException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


    public class TestApp extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getData";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getData";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login2/Service1.asmx";
    TextView tv;

boolean[] bln1=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);


    String[] arr2= call();
    boolean[] bln = {false, false, false};

     bln1 = new boolean[arr2.length];


    new AlertDialog.Builder(TestApp.this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMultiChoiceItems(arr2,
            bln,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                        boolean isChecked) {


                    if(isChecked){
                        bln1[whichButton] = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        bln1[whichButton] = false;
                    }
                }
            })
      .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


        }
      })
     .show();


      }


      public String[] call()
     {
    SoapPrimitive responsesData = null; 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( 
    SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 

    try {

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 
    System.out.println(" --- response ---- " + responsesData); 

    } catch (SocketException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    System.out.println( " ----" + responsesData );

    String serviceResponse= responsesData .toString(); 


    String[] temp; 
    String delimiter = "#"; 
    temp= serviceResponse.split(delimiter);
    System.out.println( " ---- length ---- " + temp.length); 

    return temp; 
    }


   }
```

Please can anyone help me solve my problem since everytime I run the code I get an error saying "Application terminated unexpectedly"

Thanks

Comment: Post the logcat msgs of ur application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the **web service** in the **UI thread**, which means that the UI thread is blocked till you get the response from the web service. Since Android is a mobile OS, it terminates blocked threads to improve performance.

Try writing the web service call in an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Using an Async task you can run the web service call in a background thread and your UI thread wouldn't be blocked.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Any change I could do to my code so that it becomes an ASync Task..or should I write a completely new application?

Comment: u should write new app. see this example   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693850/creat-a-login-page-in-android/6694037#6694037

Comment: @Raghu : That means the entire call method I have used will go inside an ASync task rite ?

Comment: No you don't have to create a new application, just put your web service call in the AsyncTask. Check out the [Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), if you don't get it, maybe I'll post an example. But first go through the docs, it is fairly easy.

Comment: Also what about the  code that I m using to separate values from delimiter and display as checkbox items(see code before call() )

Comment: @Aki: Ok I will first go through the docs..if any problem I will comment over here ..Thanks a lot !! :-)

Comment: No, thats alright. You can put it in the Async Task if you want to but it wouldn't block the UI thread, so no need.

Comment: @Aki:Thanks a lot !! I will try doing it and tell u soon

Comment: @Aki : I am getting errors in my code..Since I am new to Android I am finding it difficult to debug them :( ...Can u please post a simple example so that I can understand the logic of ASync ?